# Bookmark aspx page with variables

Tags: bookmarks

I know I can add `?ElementID=Value` to a URL and when the page loads, if there is a form field like `<input id="ElementID">` the word Value will be in it. Is there a way to do this for aspx pages?

Background: We are using a new service, and in every order we need to give a name and e-mail - since mine doesn't change I'd like to bookmark `service.com/order.aspx?fName=Me&uEmail=Email@company.com` to save me a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

usually the answer is no, but you can add this book mark only under the following pretenses

1) you know the code isnt doing anything else like storing session information from logging in

2) information from previous pages that prevent this page from being accessed directly

3) test it, if it works, it works.

4) dont assume it will always work, if the website changes, you might be given new variables that are random.  The page might even ignore anything after the ? mark anymore of redesigned

Comment: I know 1&2 are no. attempted 3.